# Cannot Connect to Site with Wi-Fi But Can on 3G

Tags: macos, network, web-browser

At some point earlier today, I lost the ability to connect to a site via my wireless network, powered by an Airport Express.

When I try to load the page in Chrome 23 and Safari 6.0.2 on a MacBook Air and an iMac, I get their generic "Chrome Cannot Connect" and "Safari Can't Open the Page" messages.

I get the same errors on an iPad and iPhone when connected to the wireless network. However, if I disable Wi-Fi on my iPhone and try to access the site using the AT&T 3G network.

If I disable Wi-Fi on my iPhone and try to access those sites using the AT&T 3G network.

To try to resolve this, I have shut down and restarted all devices (OS X and iOS) and then unplugged my cable modem and my Airport Express for 20+ plus minutes.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: What is the website if we may ask? Is it somewhere you shouldn't be, i.e. someone blacklisted it via your router or computer?

Comment: agreed, can you connect to other sites?

Comment: If it's a specific site, it may be a routing or DNS issue. Can you connect from another device on the Wi-Fi?

Comment: The sites are both mine, one is http://monospacial.com/ the other is a development site on that same server which I cannot share (work in progress). None of my other devices on the network (two iOS and one other Mac) can access those sites. Both sites were accessible earlier in the day.

Comment: You didn't happen to change the server's IP or something did you? I'm trying to think of an answer, but I can't - also, this question is probably better suited for SuperUSer

Comment: @ekaj You might be on to something.... On Friday, I asked my host to move my account to a different server. They did and sent a new IP address, one which I was able to connect to until mid-afternoon on Saturday.

Comment: I've experienced this problem before - sometimes it takes a while for a DNS server to propogate, and your ISP may be taking longer than the ISP being used by your 3G provider

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was indeed not with my system but with my hosting company. I'm not completely clear on how it happened, but my IP address found it's way on a blacklist, the result of a failed SSH login attempt. Though, to the best of my knowledge, I had not tried any sort of SSH login.

Answer (score 0):

Judging on what you have said in the comments (and my past experiences) my assumption is that your ISP's DNS server has not yet propogated - IE, your recent IP address change for your server has not yet been updated with your current ISP, but it has for your 3G ISP (wherever that is).

To test this theory, you could set your DNS server manually to, say Google (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) and see if your website works then - if so, this is most likely your problem.

Comment: It had propagated — I was using the site / accessing the FTP on Saturday morning. What appears to have happened is, somehow, my account has been moved back to the old server: files I added this morning (and which I accessed this morning) are not present on that server but a change I made via the cPanel before I discovered I could not access my site is reflected on this server. I have contacted tech support and am very much looking forward to their response. I will update this thread when I hear back.